# pre load images using jquery from flickr api

Tags: javascript

I'm calling a random image from flickr api.

now it's working but user need to wait for image to download,
how can I do a preload of next image so user will see the image right away.
I need to preload just the next image each time,this is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?",
    {
        //tags: keyword,
        tagmode: "any",
        format: "json"
    });


    var loadNewImage = function() {
      var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * data.items.length);
      var image_src = data.items[rnd]['media']['m'].replace("_m", "_b");
      $('.main').css('background-image', "url('" + image_src + "')");
    }

    var imageInterval = 10000;
    setInterval(loadNewImage(), imageInterval);

});
```

Comment: Are you sure it's working? `setInterval(loadNewImage(), imageInterval);` isn't correct (remove the parentheses after the function name).

Comment: ok,beside that,how can i make a preload ?

Comment: I suggest you fix the errors in your code first. In addition to that error I pointed out, your `getJSON` method is pulling in XML, not JSON, so I'm now even more amazed that the code is working. In answer to your question tho you probably need to read in all the image urls from the JSON, iterate over them creating a `new Image()` for each, and push the images into an array. Then you can just grab images from the array as and when you need.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to insert a hidden img into the document and handle its onload event.